# Routing Keyboard input to specific app

Tags: keyboard

This may sound dumb, but here's what I need to happen...  I have an extra usb keyboard attached to my mac mini.  Several pieces of software are running at any give moment.  I need to find a way to make my extra keyboard only provide input to 1 specific application, regardless of what app in currently running in the foreground.  Thoughts?

Comment: This may require a dedicated driver to capture the input from one specific keyboard and feed it into the application. Are you asking as a developer or as a user?

Comment: I’m asking as a user.